# If you happen to share the name of a very famous character, can you use it for your shop?

Tags: united-states, copyright, trademark

Assume that someone sharing the name of a famous character - just for a random Sample let's pick [Leonard McCoy](https://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/Leonard/Mccoy), [James Kirk](https://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/James/Kirk) and [Peter Parker](https://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/Peter/Parker) - just happens to want to offer services under their name in a field that happens to have overlap with the character either by trading the memorabilia/merchandise/products with those fictional characters or being in the same trade. For our example, they open a comic shop (*~'s Comics*) or work as a doctor (*Dr. Leonard McCoy*), pilot (*Fly with James Kirk*) and photographer (*Peter Parker Photography*) respectively.

Would it be a trademark or copyright infringement if they use their own name to advertise their services?